# K3s dial tcp lookup server misbehaving during letsencrypt staging

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, k3s

After succesfully hosting a first service on a single node cluster I am trying to add a second service with both its own dnsName.

The first service uses LetsEncrypt succesfully and now I am trying out the second service with a test-certifcate and the staging endpoint/clusterissuer

The error I am seeing once I describe the Letsencrypt Order is:

```
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://example.nl/.well-known/acme-challenge/9kdpAMRFKtp_t8SaCB4fM8itLesLxPkgT58RNeRCwL0': Get "http://example.nl/.well-known/acme-challenge/9kdpAMRFKtp_t8SaCB4fM8itLesLxPkgT58RNeRCwL0": dial tcp: lookup example.nl on 10.43.0.11:53: server misbehaving
```

The port that is misbehaving is pointing to the internal IP of my service/kube-dns, which means it is past my service/traefik i think.

The cluster is running on a VPS and I have also checked the example.nl domain name is added to `/etc/hosts` with the VPS's ip like so:

```
206.190.101.190 example1.nl                                                                  
206.190.101.190 example.nl
```

The error is a bit vague to me because I do not know exactly what de kube-dns is doing and why it thinks the server is misbehaving, I think maybe it is because it has now 2 domain names to handle I missed something. Anyone can shed some light on it?

Feel free to ask for more ingress or other server config!

Comment: That error usually indicates that it can't resolve the hostname. In which hosts file did you add the domain entries?

Comment: I ssh into my VPS and there I nano /etc/hosts which worked for the first service, however now I think maybe because it was the first service this works automatically?

Comment: It probably needs to be added inside the pods that run the kube-dns service, all of them.

Comment: Also, if lets encrypt can't resolve the domain - it will not be able to verify it. You have to register the domains publicly for lets encrypt to work.

Comment: The public domains are registered and working for the first service, second one is set up the same (pointing to my vps). I was thinking that once it hits my VPS it goes to the cluster (/etc/hosts) and treafik does the routing internally?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why it would work for the first service and now fails for the second in the core dns pod. I have read about adding dns to k3s but it does not answer why it would work te first time, not entirely sure I should start looking into FQDN or https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/ ?

Comment: Can you try by setting an ACME server that would validate the authorizations before having set the status of the order to "ready"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was setup right to be able to work, however this issue had definitely had something to do with DNS resolving. Not internally in the k3s cluster, but externally at the domain registrar.

I found it by using https://unboundtest.com for my domain and saw my old namespaces still being used.

Contacted the registrar and they had to change something for the domain in the DNS of the registry.

Pretty unique situation, but maybe helpful for people who also think the solution has to be found internally (inside k3s).